# error: L6236E: No section matches selector - no section to be FIRST/LAST

Tags: arm, keil

I'm new to `ARM` programming using `Keil Microvision V5.12` compiler.
I can't compile a simple assembly project  getting this error:

```
.\Objects\learn.sct(7): error: L6236E: No section matches selector - no section to be FIRST/LAST.
```

I've tried searching and couldn't find any solution for this problem.

This is what I do:

1. Create a project (*without* the startup file)
2. Add a new assembly file (learn.s)
3. Click `Build Target`.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I Added this answer for newbies,
So, After create new project do same as picture:

[image]

Comment: I'm selecting your answer as accepted because it has more upvotes than the answer that was previously accepted.

Answer (score 7):

There is no 'FIRST' object in your source code. Your scatter file likely looks something like:

```
LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00040000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00040000  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x0000A000  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
}
```

The _FIRST object that the linker wants to put into the image is the area called RESET. You do not have a RESET region in your code.
Add something along the lines of

```
AREA    RESET, DATA, READONLY
```

to your assembly file where you want execution to begin.

Create a project with the startup file and look for the AREA RESET ..... declaration and copy that.

For Cortex it looks like:

```
                AREA    RESET, DATA, READONLY
                EXPORT  __Vectors
                EXPORT  __Vectors_End
                EXPORT  __Vectors_Size

__Vectors       DCD     __initial_sp               ; Top of Stack
                DCD     Reset_Handler              ; Reset Handler
                DCD     NMI_Handler                ; NMI Handler
                DCD     HardFault_Handler          ; Hard Fault Handler
                DCD     MemManage_Handler          ; MPU Fault Handler
                DCD     BusFault_Handler           ; Bus Fault Handler
                DCD     UsageFault_Handler         ; Usage Fault Handler
                DCD     0
```

Each of those handlers needs to be declared, but you can just add the stack pointer and reset handler to get started.

Comment: Thanks a LOT! I have another question. In the code you provided, how can I access the exported data from the code (ie. __Vectors)?

Comment: In C? extern "C" the value e.g.  
extern "C" unsigned int __Vectors;
and then use it (it will likely be read only if used on a real target)

Comment: No not C. Take a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371905/how-to-write-at-least-two-areas-in-arm-assembly

Answer (score 3):

For ARM LPC the startup assembly file Startup.s is something like this:

AREA    MyStacks, DATA, NOINIT, ALIGN=2
IrqStackSpace           SPACE   IRQ_STACK_LEGTH * 4
FiqStackSpace           SPACE   FIQ_STACK_LEGTH * 4
AbtStackSpace           SPACE   ABT_STACK_LEGTH * 4
UndtStackSpace          SPACE   UND_STACK_LEGTH * 4

```
    AREA    RESET, DATA, READONLY
```

bottom_of_heap    SPACE   1

```
    AREA    RESET, DATA, READONLY
```

StackUsr          SPACE   1

Just replacing does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur If you select HSI in Clock configuration at cubeMX although you've already selected HSE in RCC. If you choose one of them (HSI/HSE) it will be solved

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem. Source (.c) fil and (.uvproj) file should same location and you can not copy from others location.So create