# How to write at least two `area`s in ARM assembly?

Tags: arm, keil

I'm trying to write an area which defines my data on the RAM, and an area for my code. I tried to do that, but I just can't make it work. I also tried using `EXPORT` and `IMPORT` but I couldn't solve various errors while using them.

```
    AREA HEAP, READWRITE, ALIGN=3
MYSTR   DCB "JaVid",0

    AREA RESET, CODE, READONLY
        ;IMPORT MYSTR

        ENTRY
        ADR R0, MYSTR   ;STRING POINTER

NEXT    LDRB R1, [R0]   ;CHARACTER HOLDER
        CMP R1, #'a'
        BLT OK
        CMP R1, #'z'
        BGT OK

        ;WE NEED TO SWITCH
        SUB R1, #'a'-'A'

OK      STRB R1, [R0], #1
        B NEXT

    END
```

Would you please give me an example of how it's done?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? It is not clear to me what you are missing

Comment: It's just [`AREA name, attribute,...`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1361290002714.html) where the attributes are `CODE`, `DATA` and such. How exactly is it going wrong?

Comment: I edited the question. This is where I get error and I don't know how to access MYSTR from CODE area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you may be having problems because you cannot use `ADR` to refer to a symbol in another `AREA`.  See [this section of the fine manual](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731148459.htm)

You probably want to use `LDR r0, =MYSTR` instead.

Also, your loop does not seem to terminate.

[Note:  It would be helpful it you showed the exact error message you are getting and the command lines you are using with the code above.]