# How to resolve error - L6236E: No section matches selector - no section to be FIRST/LAST

Tags: keil, stm32f4discovery, stm32cubemx

**I've looked into other similer questions on stackOverflow but I haven't been able to get those solutions to work.**

So, I've generated the code for STM32F4-Discovery using STM32CubeMX. First of all, on code generation, I get error message, saying "*Code is successfully generated under /path/path but MDK-ARM V5.27 project generation has a problem*".

If I ignore this error, and open the generated code on keil IDE, and straightaway just build the code, I get the following error.

[image]

Now, after searching on the internet, I found out that the solution for the error above is to add the Start-up code, and a way to do that is shown in the image below. (Ref. [error: L6236E: No section matches selector - no section to be FIRST/LAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075807/error-l6236e-no-section-matches-selector-no-section-to-be-first-last))

[image]

After including the startup code by following the steps in above image, I get following error.

[image]

I don't know if all these errors has to do with the first error that I get on cubeMX after code generation (that I keep ignoring).

In any case, someone please help me resolve this issue.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem.
After generating a project with CubeMX and adding CMSIS and FreeRTOS, I reached the same issue.

At the beginning I had the same problem with the `Error: L6236E`.
The second image in the question solved it and then I reached the `Error: L6200E`, same as you.

What I had to do to resolve my issue, was remove the CMSIS from `Drivers/CMSIS` directory and removed it from all files that contained it.

Upon a rebuild, it worked flawlessly.